# Tkinter Image in a label?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, label

Im trying to present an image inside a label, although when I print the label there is no image inside it. Here is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
newGameWindow = Toplevel()
newGameWindow.title("New Game")
newGameWindow.config(bg = "grey")
newGameWindow.geometry('600x600')


#courtImg = PhotoImage('basketballCourtTemplate.png')
courtImg = PhotoImage(file ='basketballCourtTemplate.png')


photo = Label(newGameWindow, image= courtImg, height = 200, width =200)

photo.pack()

newGameWindow.mainloop()
```

the image is located in the same file as the code. Am I loading in the image correctly?

EDIT:
this code produces exactly the same output.

```
from tkinter import *
newGameWindow = Toplevel()
newGameWindow.title("New Game")
newGameWindow.config(bg = "grey")
newGameWindow.geometry('600x600')


courtImg = PhotoImage('basketballCourtTemplate.gif')


photo = Label(newGameWindow, image= courtImg, height = 200, width =200)
photo.image = courtImg
photo.pack()

newGameWindow.mainloop()
```

EDIT:
All it needed was `courtImg = PhotoImage(file='basketballCourtTemplate.gif')`

Comment: [Why do my Tkinter images not appear?](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm)